# Django, reading the source code and main Documentation, "side by side"

Tags: python, django

I'm reading Django 1.5's [main documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/). As I move forward, I'd like to see some of the real implementation to have a better grasp of the concepts.

I know that the source code is on GitHub. I forked the source and have to search by using my favorite editor to find stuff.

Do you know any online alternative for "searching" among its source code? I mean except for googling each function over and over ...

**Update**: based upon the provided answer, a good Solution is using **[ack](http://betterthangrep.com/)**! It's an awesome tool for searching stuff within source codes ..

For Debian-based distros, you can install it by using:

```
sudo apt-get install ack-grep; sudo ln -s $(which ack-grep) /usr/local/bin/ack
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should clone the sources, and use [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) to search.